Doubts tsna and umap
Load data into variables:
First of all, you can use applications external to R to inspect what
type of data you are going to be using and how to deal with it.
Once you have inspected and decided, go for it!
# --------------------------
## [#1] Read the data
# --------------------------
## Read data into separate variables
P1_data = ""
P2_data = ""

Check the data
Once loaded into R, check if the data matches what you expected and take
a brief view of the data.
# just print a small head of the data


::: {.question_box data-latex=""}
Q1: What are column names for each original dataframe? Are there
duplicates?
:::
::: {.question_box data-latex=""}
ANSWER Q1:
...
:::
Adapt the data accordingly and merge both tables of observations
Since we need columns of the tables to represent variables and rows to
be samples, individuals, we need to transpose the data of the
matrices. Then, we merged experiments into a single data.frame.
# --------------------------
## [#2] Adapt the data
# --------------------------
X1 = ""
X2 = ""

## Merge
X = ""


Now, check that we transformed the data correctly:


Get metadata associated:
Create a dataframe with metadata. We might like to include the names of
the samples as rows, the replicates IDs (1,2 or A,B,...) and the type of
sample as described in the treatment file: T: treated, U: untreated, N:
non-treated.
Hello, I don't understand the structure nor what it means... Any kind soul who can solve my doubts?
Thanks in advance.
